# File is downloaded but content is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-applications, web-config

i am using WCF to upload and download a file. and i am using the following the for download.

```
try
        {
            MyService.IWITSService clientDownload = new WITSServiceClient();
            MyService.DownloadRequest requestData = new DownloadRequest();
            MyService.RemoteFileInfo fileInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();
            requestData.ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

            fileInfo = clientDownload.DownloadFile(requestData);

            Response.BufferOutput = false;   // to prevent buffering 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[6500000];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = fileInfo.FileExt;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.FileName);

            bytesRead = fileInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {

                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new byte[6500000];
                    bytesRead = fileInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                }
                else
                {
                    bytesRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        }
```

file is downloaded but file data is not display. file size is same as an actual
 size. can any one help me where i have to change..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in the debugger to verify that the data is being read from the server?

Comment: yes.. data is read from the server..

Comment: what type of file,you are uploading?

Comment: .docx file, or any other file...

Comment: have you checked all required conditions were met?

Comment: all required condition is true, and got byte array as file data.

Comment: ContentType may differ for each file,specify the respective contenttype.Eg:.xls=>x-excel; By default,you specify "octet-stream"  and try it.

Comment: MahaSwetha the OP is not UpLoading a file he or she is downloading the file

Comment: Use a Hex viewer or a file-compare utility to find out what actually happens.

Comment: put a break point after this line fileInfo = clientDownload.DownloadFile(requestData); and report back what fileInfo also let us know what the file size or file Length is..?

Comment: i have also try this but not success. HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Comment: For .docx file,place this contenttype = "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; try it for docx file,let me know,whether it works or not.

Comment: content type in this line HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = fileInfo.FileExt; what is fileInfo.Filext..? it should be something like this for example             var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Comment: fileInfo.FileExt="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.word" fileInfo.FileName="ABS.docx" AND FileSize is 12.5KB. Downloaded file's size is 13 KB. But Content is missing

Comment: if you were doing this in asp.net you could also try something like this for example             var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; or something like this which I just tested and it works for me in my asp.net web application 

Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.xls"
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: if the file has a size of 13KB but there is nothing visibly there when you open the file then perhaps the file is not being flushed properly are you closing the FileStream..?

Comment: after the first Response.Flush(); you need to close that Response so add the following code Response.Close(); and comment out the one in the finally code block. you have redundant code in that finally block

Comment: Before Response.Flush(); i closed the response and got this exception The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.

Comment: What are you saying.. you are not making sense.. what is the exact file path on the server where you are wanting to download the file.. can you use WebClient Class instead and download async...?

Comment: Noticed something else in your code.. where are you disposing or setting these values  MyService.IWITSService clientDownload = new WITSServiceClient();
            MyService.DownloadRequest requestData = new DownloadRequest();
            MyService.RemoteFileInfo fileInfo = new RemoteFileInfo(); ....?

Comment: @MindFresher: Have you tried to remove the two `Close()` calls from the *finally* block as I've proposed in my answer? I'd appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to call neither `Response.Close()` nor `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()`. It interrupts the connection to the client.

The documentation of [HttpResponse.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx) says:

> This method terminates the connection to the client in an abrupt
>   manner and is not intended for normal HTTP request processing. The
>   method sends a reset packet to the client, which can cause response
>   data that is buffered on the server, the client, or somewhere in
>   between to be dropped.
>
> You might use this method in response to an attack by a malicious HTTP
>   client. However, typically you should call CompleteRequest instead if
>   you want to jump ahead to the EndRequest event and send a response to
>   the client.

So reduce the `finally` code to:

```
finally
{
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```